# Phonegap - Local storage not working - Android

Tags: android, cordova, local-storage

I'm using Local Storage to pass values between pages in order to create a scroll to effect (user clicks link and is scrolled to particular part of the page based on ID)

I was previously using cookies but that didn't seem to work on Android, I read that local storage was supported so switched over to that. It works completely fine when in the browser but as soon as its packaged as a native app I lose all functionality? The API states that it should be supported, any ideas?

Here's my code:

Base URL:

```
var storage = window.localStorage;
$("a.scroll_link").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var value = $(this).attr("id");

        storage.setItem("key",value);

    console.log(value);

    window.location=$(this).attr("href");
});
```

Receiving URL:

```
$(function () { 

var value = window.localStorage.getItem("key");

if (value != "" && value != "undefined" && value != null) {
    var storage = window.localStorage;
    storage.setItem("key",value);
    var scroll_type = "";

    if ($.browser.webkit) {
        scroll_type = "body";
    } else {
        scroll_type = "html";
    }

    $(scroll_type)
        .stop()
        .animate({
        //get top-position of target-element and set it as scroll target
        scrollTop: ($("#" + value).offset().top - 25)
        //scrolldelay: 1.5 seconds
    }, {
        duration: 1500,
        complete: function () {
            storage.removeItem("key");
        },
    });
  }
});
```

The code works fine in the browser just not natively, any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Use document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false) instead of  $(function(){...}

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready

Comment: Got it working now thanks, I deleted the app from my device and then re-run the code and it now all works, I am however now having problems with using localStorage together with iScroll, it seems I can have one or the other and not both.. any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1):

1.Glad to know you solve your first problem. As gmh04 say, I think you should replace your init event with 'deviceready' which is triggered when the app start running.

2.
You mean window.localStorage.getItem("key") return null in Receiving URL?
I do not exactly encounter a problem as what you describe. However, you may try to move your code in receiving url to the same page of base url. I have tried for times and be very sure that the localStorage will work in the same page.

Comment: The getItem seems to be working okay with the value being passed through, what it doesn't seem to do is animate and scrollTo the location on the page that matches the ID of the value..

Answer (score 1):

I would like add that there's a bug on the 2.6.0 version of cordova.js that make localStorage don't work on Android:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-3063

On the 2.5.0 version it works perfectly, and it is already fix on the 2.7.0 rc.