# Cordova Json . array local storage isn´t workind on android

Tags: android, json, cordova, local-storage

I´m trying to do an array to storage data with local storage. it works pretty well on google emulator. but isn´t working on my android device.
I found this code on the internet to put array in localstorage, and it works.

```
Storage.prototype.setArray = function (key, obj) {
    return this.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(obj))
}
Storage.prototype.getArray = function (key) {
    return JSON.parse(this.getItem(key))
}
```

then i create an function to get and set the data there.

```
function teste() {
    var bd = [];
    bd = window.localStorage.getArray("banco");
    var nome = $('#name2').val();
    alert(nome);
    var area = $('#textarea2').val();
    alert(area);
    var meuservico = new servico(nome, area);
    bd.push(meuservico);
    alert(bd[0].nome);
    window.localStorage.setArray("banco", bd);

}
```

and I also made an object called service.

```
function servico(nome,area){
    this.nome = nome;
    this.area = area;
}
```

this code work! but only on browser . how do I make it work on android? I don´t really wanna work with strings in localstorage. please help me!.

I tried with this too and didn´t work on device either.

```
localStorage.setItem('session', JSON.stringify(session));
var restoredSession = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('session'));
```

Comment: when i say google emulater i´m talkin about broswer emulator. sorry for my English

Comment: Have you tried with window.localStorage.setItem('session', JSON.stringify(session))? This worked for me, what is the android version of your device?

Comment: yes didn´t work for me my version is 4.0

Comment: I assume, you included cordova.js script and you put your code inside the deviceReady function, right?

Comment: yes i did . but the funtion needs to be inside the device ready?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15157245/phonegap-local-storage-not-working-android check this out